# T-SQL, how to do this group by query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql

I have a view with this information:

> **TableA** (IDTableA, IDTableB, IDTableC, Active, date,  ...)

For each register in `TableA` and each register in `tableC`, I want the register of `tableB` that have the max date and is active.

```
select IDTableA, IDtableC, IDTableB, Date, Active
from myView
where Active = 1
group by IDTableA, IDTableC
Having Max(Date)
order by IDTableA;
```

This query works with `SQLite`, but if I try this query in `SQL Server` I get an error that say that `IDTableB` in the `select` is not contained in the `group` clause.

I know that in theory the first query in the SQLite shouldn't work, but do it.

How can I do this query in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: Include it in the `GROUP BY` clause. What `HAVING MAX(Date)` equals what, exactly?

Comment: Is this for SQL-Server or for SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
select * from table1 b
where active = 1
and date = (select max(date) from table1
            where idtablea = b.idtablea
            and idtablec = b.idtablec
            and active = 1);
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0bdae/3/0)**

Comment: There is no need to put a `GROUP BY` condition to get the desired result.

Comment: this is using only the view or I have to use the three tables?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía This is just using the view. Replace `table1` with `TableA` (which I assume is the name of your view).

Answer (score 2):

According to SQL 92, if you use `GROUP BY` clause, then in `SELECT` output expression list you can only use columns mentioned in `GROUP BY` list, or any other columns but they must be wrapped in aggregate functions like `count()`, `sum()`, `avg()`, `max()`, `min()` and [so on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138031.aspx).

Some servers like MSSQL, Postgres are strict about this rule, but for example MySQL and SQLite are very relaxed and forgiving - and this is why it surprised you.

Long story short - if you want this to work in MSSQL, adhere to SQL92 requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This query in SQLServer

```
select IDTableA, IDtableC, IDTableB, Date, Active
from myView v1
where Active = 1
  AND EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM myView v2
              group by v2.IDTableA, v2.IDTableC
              Having Max(v2.Date) = v1.Date
              )
order by v1.IDTableA;
```

OR

Also in SQLServer2005+ you can use CTE with ROW_NUMBER

```
;WITH cte AS
 (              
  select IDTableA, IDtableC, IDTableB, [Date], Active,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IDTableA, IDTableC ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn
  from myView v1
  where Active = 1
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY IDTableA
```